# Decomposing a GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, db2

Assuming I have a table `SomeTable` with the following data:

```
Primary Key    Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5    Num
    1           dat1       abc1       dat3       dat4       por7       1
    2           dat1       gcd4       dat3       dat4       yrt8       6
    3           dat1       iut7       dat3       dat4       asd6       2  
    4          other1     other2     other3     other4     other5      4
```

Another table `SomeTableGrouped` with a "Group Byed" version created using a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTableGrouped
SELECT Column1, Column3, Column4, SUM(Num)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Column1, Column3, Column4

Primary Key    Column1    Column3    Column4    Num
    100         dat1       dat3       dat4       9
    200        other1     other3     other4      4
```

What I'd like to be able to do is, if I have a primary key of `SomeTableGrouped`, I need to be able to tell which specific rows from `SomeTable` it came from.

Example:

In a separate table `RandomTable`, I have data like this:

```
Primary Key    Column1    SomeTableGroupedId
    1           dat1             100
    2           dat2             100
```

If I look at the first row, I need to be able to list out row 1 - 3 from `SomeTable`

How can I do this? I can't change the schema very much (ie. I can only add new columns, remove columns, add a new table) so a dirty solution is perfectly fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT id
FROM SomeTable
INNER JOIN SomeTableGrouped ON
    (SomeTable.Column1 = SomeTableGrouped.Column1) AND
    (SomeTable.Column2 = SomeTableGrouped.Column2) AND
    (SomeTable.Column3 = SomeTableGrouped.Column3) 
WHERE SomeTableGrouped.id = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to create all those tables, you only need `SomeTable`. But here we go...

If you want to find the IDs of the records that summed up, just relate them as they were created:

```
select st.PrimaryKey as STPK,  stg.PrimaryKey as STGPK
from SomeTable st 
inner join SomeTableGrouped stg
on (st.Column1 = stg.Column1 and 
    st.Column3 = stg.Column3 and 
    st.Column5 = stg.Column5)
```

However, you should not even have created `SomeTableGrouped`as a table. It could be a view (look [here to see how create views in DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000935.htm)).

That way, you make sure data is always up-to-date and you don't have to worry about back tracking ("what if `Num` gets updated?").